# Report accidental call of a Python test case module without `-m unittest`

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-module

By accident I called my Python unit tests with the following command:

```
coverage run -m tests.unit.Tokens
```

This executed some code and reported a coverage report. But actually the coverage looked like initializing only. There was no error message and no exception.
[image]

After some search and debug, I found that I missed the package name `unittest` between `-m` and my test case module. Thus the module "executed" was not `unittest` with parameter `tests.unit.Tokens`. It executed the test case declaration module directly.

**Example call:**

```
coverage run -m tests.unit.Tokens
```

**should report something like:**

```
Module 'tests.unit.Tokens' needed to be loaded by Pythons `unittest`.
Use 'python3 -m unitest test.unit.Tokens'
```

---

What can I add/implement/overwrite, so calling the module directly gives an error message?

I could imagine, the could would look like what we use in out main Python files:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  # this is the entry point
```

Comment: I do believe you've answered your own question.. have you tried `if __name__ == "__main__":` and run into an error?

Comment: @Aaron I was not sure if execution with `-m <module>` is executed the same way as executing with shebang. But yes, it also runs in the `__main__` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module launched via `python -m` is also executed in the namespace `__main__`. Thus the following code in a (declarative) testcase module can give a hint how to execute the testcases correctly.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("ERROR: you called a testcase declaration file as an executable module.")
  print("Use: 'python -m unitest <testcase module>'")
```